# Negative and positive measurement -2 V, 2 V Arduino

Tags: arduino

I want to make a measurement of VDC with high sensitivity (best 1 mV) on a range of -2 V to 2 V.

I know that there are voltage dividers and operational controllers, but I don't understand how to use them.

Can someone provide me some names of ready components which I can buy and connect to an Arduino to achieve my target? Or, if not posible, please tell me how to easily do it.

I read a lot of articles about it but there is always a graph I don't understand (there is no marking of the slots of the Arduino I should use and where the sensor cables should be placed).

Comment: In this case, you will want to buy an add-on board, called a *shield*, for the Arduino. Have a conversation with the manufacturers to make sure it will do the job you want, first, of course. This will provide you also with the necessary software to operate the board. And the manufacturer can help you make a proper connection, as well. Given your apparent state of knowledge, this isn't something you want to design and build for yourself. Even with all this help, you will have enough yet to learn and deal with (offset, differential and integral non-linearity, noise-related questions, and more.)

Comment: The -2V to 2V signal comes from somewhere, and it is important to know the impedance (output resistance) of that source. If this impedance is high, and your circuit draws too much current from it, then the voltage will change and you won't get the mV precision you want. So you must give this information in the question. Note if you don't want to build anything, there are multimeters with a serial port output, that can be useful to measure a voltage and report it to a computer.

Comment: I want measure blood voltage in liquide.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a range of 4 volts with an offset of 2 volts. The Arduino has a 10 bit ADC so the best you can get is a resolution of 4/1024 = 3.9 mV per count. Dealing with the offset requires an amplifier to provide 0-5 VDC to the Arduino. Here is a circuit that should do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu2wUM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Amplifier with offset]

Comment: Thank you but you gave me same answear i saw on other sites. Im expecting more detiled answear like with pins should i use to do it on arduino nano.